# Select distinct on max value column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns:
Policy, ProcessCode, ProcessedOn, GWP (and others)

The table has multiple lines for the same policy based on those 3 other columns with different values.

How can I select only the policies with the MAX value on column GWP ?

Thanks!
[see example of data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXl7k.png)

Comment: Use `TOP (1)`..?

Comment: @LARNU not working for me:

Comment: "not working" doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `order by` and `top`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
order by gwp desc;
```

Comment: *cough* Close as Duplicate. *cough*

Comment: not ok. I have multiple lines with other policies in the table.
using top (1) and order by policy ; gwp desc will display only 1 policy

Comment: That is what you ask for, @encrypted ; 1 row...

Comment: @larnu sorry, I`m new to stackoverflow. I've added a new image of data.

Comment: Images don't explain anything here, @encrypted .

Comment: Ok. I have the following columns: policy, ProcessCode, ProcessedOn and GWP.
Each policy may have multiple lines.
I have to select only the lines with MAX GWP for each policy

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68666502/edit) to improve your question, @encrypted . As it stands, you want the "top" row and those duplicates tell you how to do that.

Comment: I already checked those duplicates, without understanding their answers.

Comment: @larnu I've edited my question. can you please mark it as opened ? I didn't figure it out from those 2 other questions mentioned by you. thank you.

Comment: No need to, this is just another duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) @encrypted . I've added the dupe to the list.

Comment: can you explain me please based on my table ? I cannot figure out the answer from those 2 other question

Comment: All the information is in the answer(s) on the dupe, @encrypted . If you don't understand the answer, I would suggest you post a new question, showing your attempts to implement the solutions on the other question, and explaining why they didn't work. Though, with respect, reading the answers on the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) will tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: cannot add other question today....